# Given a 3 x 3 matrix or any n x n matrix, why would my following function not find the diagonal difference?

Tags: c++, matrix, diagonal

```
int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
    int sum; int n = arr.size(); int ld = 0; int rd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > n; i++)
    {
        rd += arr[i][i];
        ld += arr[i][n-1-i];
    }
    sum = rd - ld; 
    return abs(sum);
}
```

I have done the work on my whiteboard and the for loop should find the sum of the right diagonal and left diagonal on a 3 x 3 matrix, but my code is supposedly not working. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is logically incorrect. Your loop should be:

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

Anyway,the below code will run

```
int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
        int sum; int n = arr.size(); int ld = 0; int rd = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                rd += arr[i][i];
                ld += arr[i][n-1-i];
            }
             sum = rd - ld; 
            return abs(sum);
        }
```